# Repeating rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I would like to 'double' (or triple, or....). I am not trying to concatenate a dataframe with itself, i.e. have one full copy of the df stacked on top of another full copy of the df.

Starting with this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from IPython.display import display

A_csv = """country
Afghanistan
Brazil
China"""
with StringIO(A_csv) as fp:
    A = pd.read_csv(fp)
display(A)
```

result

```
       country
0  Afghanistan
1       Brazil
2        China
```

I want to get something like this; the index and indentation aren't so important.

```
     country
0  Afghanistan
1  Afghanistan
2  Brazil
3  Brazil
4  China
5  China
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A.values.repeat(2), columns=A.columns)
df

       country
0  Afghanistan
1  Afghanistan
2       Brazil
3       Brazil
4        China
5        China
```

---

For N-D dataframes, the solution should be extended using an `axis` parameter in `repeat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(A.values.repeat(2, axis=0), columns=A.columns)
```

Comment: Trying this on 3x3 df gives this error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 18), indices imply (3, 18); is there a way to make this work for larger DF's?

Comment: @cumin Yes, add an “axis=1” parameter to repeat.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(A.values.repeat(2, axis = 1), columns=A.columns)   ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 3), indices imply (3, 3)

Comment: @cumin Ah crap, it should be axis=0, haha. My bad. Though if it still doesn’t work, I’ll recommend putting up another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.repeat

```
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df['country'], 2)).reset_index(drop = True)

    country
0   Afghanistan
1   Afghanistan
2   Brazil
3   Brazil
4   China
5   China
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df]*2,axis=0).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
Out[56]: 
       country
0  Afghanistan
1  Afghanistan
2       Brazil
3       Brazil
4        China
5        China
```