# How to remove Repetive columns and add a datetime column to this data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that looks like this all together in a single sheet

Sales for 2018-01-04:

| Salesperson | north | east | south | west |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| David [7177] | 794 | 2971 | 1228 | 5529 |
| Janet (3655) | 1964 | 7401 | 7315 | 6742 |
| Tim (2213) | 2123 | 147 | 9644 | 1244 |
| Mark (1336) | 1014 | 3422 | 1909 | 5052 |
| Total | 17894 | 2577 | 29103 | 29691 |

Sales for 2018-01-05:

| Salesperson | north | east | south | west |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Caed (717) | 794 | 2971 | 1228 | 5529 |
| Caed (717) | 1964 | 7401 | 7315 | 6742 |
| Tim (2213) | 2123 | 147 | 9644 | 1244 |
| Mark (1336) | 1014 | 3422 | 1909 | 5052 |
| Total | 17894 | 2577 | 29103 | 29691 |

The sales for each day is included in the rows
Also I'll like to remove the total rows
Here is a screenshot of the sheet
[image: sheet screehot]

I will like the The resulting output should be like this

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), see specific details on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464). [Do not use images of data or code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16343464).

Comment: @eddie. Can you provide a screenshot of the sheet, please?

Comment: I have added the sheet screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it where each chain is roughly equivalent to a Power Query's [*applied step*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/applied-steps) :

```
df = (
    pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)
        .assign(Date= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[0], format="Sales for: %Y-%m-%d",
                errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%A, %B %#d, %Y").ffill())
        .pipe(lambda x: x.join(x[0].str.extract(
              r"(?P<Sales_Person>\w+)\s+\((?P<Sales_Person_ID>.+)\)")))
        .dropna(subset="Sales_Person_ID").drop(columns=0)
        .set_index(["Sales_Person", "Sales_Person_ID", "Date"], append=True)
        .set_axis(["North", "East", "South", "West"], axis=1)
        .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name="Region", value_name="Sales").reset_index()
        .sort_values(by="level_0").drop(columns="level_0").reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

​Output :

```
print(df)

    Sales_Person Sales_Person_ID                     Date Region Sales
0          James            1769  Monday, January 1, 2018  North   373
1          James            1769  Monday, January 1, 2018   East  5209
2          James            1769  Monday, January 1, 2018   West   789
3          James            1769  Monday, January 1, 2018  South  3552
..           ...             ...                      ...    ...   ...
188         Greg            5661  Monday, January 8, 2018   East  5434
189         Greg            5661  Monday, January 8, 2018  North  2995
190         Greg            5661  Monday, January 8, 2018  South  1660
191         Greg            5661  Monday, January 8, 2018   West  9195

[192 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this source code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define the dataset
dataset = """
Sales for: 2018-01-04 |Salesperson | north | east |south |west| |:-----------|-----|----|-----|----:| |David[7177]|794 |2971| 1228|5529| |Janet(3655)| 1964|7401|7315 |6742| |Tim (2213) |2123 |147 | 9644|1244| |Mark(1336) |1014 |3422|1909 |5052| |Total |17894|2577|29103|29691|

Sales for: 2018-01-05 |Salesperson|north|east|south|west| |:-----------|-----|----|-----|----| |Caed (717) |794 |2971| 1228|5529| |Caed (717) | 1964|7401|7315 |6742| |Tim (2213) |2123 |147 | 9644|1244| |Mark(1336) |1014 |3422|1909 |5052| |Total |17894|2577|29103| 29691|
"""

# Split the dataset into individual sections based on "Sales for:"
sections = dataset.split("Sales for:")

# Remove empty sections
sections = [section.strip() for section in sections if section.strip()]

# Initialize an empty list to store dataframes for each section
dataframes = []

# Process each section
for section in sections:
    # Split the section into lines
    lines = section.strip().split("\n")
    
    # Extract the header row
    header = lines[1].split("|")[1:-1]
    
    # Extract the data rows
    data = [line.split("|")[1:-1] for line in lines[3:-1]]
    
    # Create a dataframe for the section
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
    
    # Append the dataframe to the list
    dataframes.append(df)

# Concatenate all dataframes into a single dataframe
merged_df = pd.concat(dataframes)

# Print the merged dataframe
print(merged_df)
```

Do you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435631/repeating-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe) about *repeat*?

Comment: The dataset is not from different source, it's store in a single sheet albeit  a row is representing date at the top of each day
Also I provide a picture of what I wanted the output to look like

Comment: Do you try the repeat feature in pandas, I add a  link in my answer.